# AJAX cross domain request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have my JavaScript files on my main domain and I want to do some calls from the subdomain.

I have added:

```
url: "http://domain.com/ajax.php"
```

So the full code is:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://domain.com/ajax.php",
        data: {
            var1: var1,
            var2: var2
        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

But on Firebug it shows the request as **red** and it fails to respond. Also the POST parameters are there as they should.

Should I create a new JS file on the subdomain and add the necessary codes and do from there the AJAX calls?

**EDIT:** using JSONP code

I am using this on `localhost/ajax.php`, which I call from `sub.localhost`

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'id=10',
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
```

and the ajax.php contains:

```
<?php
echo $_GET["id"];
?>
```

Comment: what are the 2 domains?  is your server erroring out?

Comment: at the moment i am testing at localhost, no errors, just doesnt return anything back.

Comment: try testing on the actual domains. localhost to domain is more problematic, though see possible solutions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to enable cross-domain requests.

Read this: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jQuery 1.5+ you can use:

```
$.ajax({

    crossDomain:true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://domain.com/ajax.php",
    data: {
        var1: var1,
        var2: var2
    },
    success: function(data){

    }

});
```

From the DOCS:

crossDomain(added 1.5)

`Default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests`

If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain

Answer (score 0):

For subdomain calls you have two options:

1. Use [document.domain](http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/) on both sides.
2. Use jsonP, either via jQuery 1.5's crossDomain [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) specification, or [directly](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

Comment: with jsonp it doesnt even execute the ajax request on the subdomain

Comment: post your jsonp code (on both the caller and callee sides) and i'll take a look.

Comment: Ah, your response needs to be json formatted: `{id: 5}` for example.

Comment: updating the votes.php to  $array = array(
  'id' => $_GET["id"]
 );
 echo json_encode($array); , gives the formatted json.. but on the subdomain it seems like it doesnt even see that there is an ajax request when i click the button because nothing happens on firebug... it doesnt even show the request

Comment: I see that you specified a jsonp callback. Do this for simplicity sake for now:  `$.getJSON('http://localhost/ajax.php?id=10&callback=?', function(data) { console.log(data)});`

Comment: still it doesnt see that there is an ajax request to do.. really weird.. if i add console.log('1') i can see that the button is really pressed... i cant understand why it cant recognise the ajax code
**edit**: as i can see when i dont add the callback it sends the request and gets a 200 OK request but doesnt return nothing.. also the request appears as red in firebug

Comment: have you tried not on localhost but on your actual domains? do a test there just to make sure. also, try having ajax.php return something static just to be sure there's nothing going on over there. have the whole page just be `{id: 5}` for now.